# Dynamically changing background-image in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am taking a small strip of each of my posts images by dynamically changing the background image of a class and making that class the image. The problem is, in the loop each posts background image is the same (the last post in the loop). How do I get each post to show the proper background image?

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<style media="screen">
  .foobar { background-image: url(<%= post.image %>); }
</style>  

<div class="foobar"></div>


<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same class and its background image is being overridden by the following  tags.

Solution: for each of your posts create a different class like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <style media="screen">
    .foobar-post-<%= post.id %> { background-image: url(<%= post.image %>); }
  </style>  
  <div class="foobar-post-<%= post.id %>"></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="foobar" style="background-image: url(<%= post.image %>)"></div>
<% end %>
```

Inline styles aren't great, but inline style tags are even worse. You should also look into [`image_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path) for referencing image files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your way is probably cleaner but for some reason creates a css problem for me. Still deserves an upvote :)